# How do i implement friendship functionality in database using sequelize for social media demo app

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm building a social media demo app and to add friends functionality to that app.
In database I am thinking about making new table(model in sequelize) which contains `user1` id and `user2` id and a status with one character (accepted, rejected etc).

I tried implementing it but faced some issue: Now i need to have unique key but for combination of user 1 and user 2 (pair of user1 and user2 id).

How do I implement something like this using sequelize and also I don't think this is the best way to do it, so if you have a better way please let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your description is somewhat lacking and missing some components. However it is clear enough to see what you are describing
is a many-to-many (m:m) relationship. It is just that the  both sides come from the same table. While not the most common relationship,
neither is it too unusual. Further the resolution is the same as any other m:m. Create another table that has the key to both sides
as foreign keys. There is one slightly unusual twist in that the combination (parent1, parent2)(P1,P2) and the combination (P2,P1)
should be considered the same. This introduces a slight twist to the norm; instead of generating a PK from the the parent columns
the PK will be just be sequence generated (technically the PK is not required unless there are anticipated child tables of it).
We then create a unique index on the ordered pair (P1,P2). So something along the line of:

```
create table friends( f_id integer generated always as identity
                    , user_id_1 integer  not null 
                    , user_id_2 integer  not null
                    , status  varchar(1) not null default 'P' 
                    , friends_since date not null default now()::date  
                    , constraint friends_pk primary key(f_id)
                    , constraint f2user_1_fk foreign key(user_id_1)
                                 references users(user_id)
                    , constraint f2user_2_fk foreign key(user_id_2)
                                 references users(user_id) 
                    , constraint cannot_friend_self
                                 check (user_id_1 != user_id_2)
                    );
--
-- unique index to recognize (P1,P2) = (P2,P1)                  
create unique index already_friends on friends  
        ( least(user_id_1,user_id_2), greatest(user_id_1,user_id_2) );
```

See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d09c2558816e54833c7bb20988c3148e) for examples. The bi-directional nature of Friends table causes additional complications within the queries. Typically I hide complication within SQL functions. I have also added a couple useful functions. You should be able to uses these as examples. Note, since they are SQL functions you can extract the statement and convert to a parameterized query.  

Sorry, I do not know sequelize so I will not guess at the translation, but there seem to be many examples of the internet for all the above.